# Nginx + configuration error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, nginx, unicorn

I've been trying to config a vh file but I end up in this error:

I have this config file scraped from unicorns github site.

```
# This is example contains the bare mininum to get nginx going with
# Unicorn or Rainbows! servers.  Generally these configuration settings
# are applicable to other HTTP application servers (and not just Ruby
# ones), so if you have one working well for proxying another app
# server, feel free to continue using it.
#
# The only setting we feel strongly about is the fail_timeout=0
# directive in the "upstream" block.  max_fails=0 also has the same
# effect as fail_timeout=0 for current versions of nginx and may be
# used in its place.
#
# Users are strongly encouraged to refer to nginx documentation for more
# details and search for other example configs.

# you generally only need one nginx worker unless you're serving
# large amounts of static files which require blocking disk reads
worker_processes 1;

# # drop privileges, root is needed on most systems for binding to port 80
# # (or anything < 1024).  Capability-based security may be available for
# # your system and worth checking out so you won't need to be root to
# # start nginx to bind on 80
user nobody nogroup; # for systems with a "nogroup"
# user nobody nobody; # for systems with "nobody" as a group instead

# Feel free to change all paths to suite your needs here, of course
pid /tmp/nginx.pid;
error_log /tmp/nginx.error.log;

events {
  worker_connections 1024; # increase if you have lots of clients
  accept_mutex off; # "on" if nginx worker_processes > 1
  # use epoll; # enable for Linux 2.6+
  # use kqueue; # enable for FreeBSD, OSX
}

http {
  # nginx will find this file in the config directory set at nginx build time
  include mime.types;

  # fallback in case we can't determine a type
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  # click tracking!
  access_log /tmp/nginx.access.log combined;

  # you generally want to serve static files with nginx since neither
  # Unicorn nor Rainbows! is optimized for it at the moment
  sendfile on;

  tcp_nopush on; # off may be better for *some* Comet/long-poll stuff
  tcp_nodelay off; # on may be better for some Comet/long-poll stuff

  # we haven't checked to see if Rack::Deflate on the app server is
  # faster or not than doing compression via nginx.  It's easier
  # to configure it all in one place here for static files and also
  # to disable gzip for clients who don't get gzip/deflate right.
  # There are other gzip settings that may be needed used to deal with
  # bad clients out there, see http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpGzipModule
  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_min_length 500;
  gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_types text/plain text/html text/xml text/css
             text/comma-separated-values
             text/javascript application/x-javascript
             application/atom+xml;

  # this can be any application server, not just Unicorn/Rainbows!
  upstream app_server {
    # fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
    # to return a good HTTP response (in case the Unicorn master nukes a
    # single worker for timing out).

    # for UNIX domain socket setups:
    server unix:/tmp/.sock fail_timeout=0;

    # for TCP setups, point these to your backend servers
    # server 192.168.0.7:8080 fail_timeout=0;
    # server 192.168.0.8:8080 fail_timeout=0;
    # server 192.168.0.9:8080 fail_timeout=0;
  }

  server {
    # enable one of the following if you're on Linux or FreeBSD
    # listen 80 default deferred; # for Linux
    # listen 80 default accept_filter=httpready; # for FreeBSD

    # If you have IPv6, you'll likely want to have two separate listeners.
    # One on IPv4 only (the default), and another on IPv6 only instead
    # of a single dual-stack listener.  A dual-stack listener will make
    # for ugly IPv4 addresses in $remote_addr (e.g ":ffff:10.0.0.1"
    # instead of just "10.0.0.1") and potentially trigger bugs in
    # some software.
    # listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on; # deferred or accept_filter recommended

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name _;

    # ~2 seconds is often enough for most folks to parse HTML/CSS and
    # retrieve needed images/icons/frames, connections are cheap in
    # nginx so increasing this is generally safe...
    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # path for static files
    root /path/to/app/current/public;

    # Prefer to serve static files directly from nginx to avoid unnecessary
    # data copies from the application server.
    #
    # try_files directive appeared in in nginx 0.7.27 and has stabilized
    # over time.  Older versions of nginx (e.g. 0.6.x) requires
    # "if (!-f $request_filename)" which was less efficient:
    # http://bogomips.org/unicorn.git/tree/examples/nginx.conf?id=v3.3.1#n127
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
      # an HTTP header important enough to have its own Wikipedia entry:
      #   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

      # enable this if you forward HTTPS traffic to unicorn,
      # this helps Rack set the proper URL scheme for doing redirects:
      # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      # pass the Host: header from the client right along so redirects
      # can be set properly within the Rack application
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

      # we don't want nginx trying to do something clever with
      # redirects, we set the Host: header above already.
      proxy_redirect off;

      # set "proxy_buffering off" *only* for Rainbows! when doing
      # Comet/long-poll/streaming.  It's also safe to set if you're using
      # only serving fast clients with Unicorn + nginx, but not slow
      # clients.  You normally want nginx to buffer responses to slow
      # clients, even with Rails 3.1 streaming because otherwise a slow
      # client can become a bottleneck of Unicorn.
      #
      # The Rack application may also set "X-Accel-Buffering (yes|no)"
      # in the response headers do disable/enable buffering on a
      # per-response basis.
      # proxy_buffering off;

      proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }

    # Rails error pages
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
      root /path/to/app/current/public;
    }
  }
}
```

I receive this error when trying to start the server, not that I have changed paths and such to my own paths but I don't even get there...

```
Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] "worker_processes" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf:18
```

What am I doing wrong? I have compiled nginx myself and installed it into /usr/local/... This is my nginx.conf file:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*; 

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl                  on;
    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

I have also tried overwrite the /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf file with the unicorn config file but that doesn't help...

Comment: Bahh. I know what the problem was, just had to delete everything except the "server"-settings in the default.conf in sites-available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put everything outside of server settings in the nginx.conf file.