# nginx directive is not allowed here in unicorn's example nginx.conf

Tags: nginx, unicorn

I'm using nginx 1.4.1. After copying [unicorn's example of `nginx.conf`](https://github.com/defunkt/unicorn/blob/master/examples/nginx.conf), I found out the settings must be moved to different directives. I still couldn't manage to place the following settings in the `nginx.conf` file: `worker_processes`, `user`, `pid` and `events` block. When I place them as it is now, the log shows `directive is not allowed here`. What should I fix?

```
worker_processes 1;
user deployer sudo; # for systems with a "nogroup"
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 1024; # increase if you have lots of clients
  accept_mutex off; # "on" if nginx worker_processes > 1
}

upstream abc {
  ...
}

server {
  ...
}
```

## Update 1

I know about this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15208135/nginx-configuration-error), but it's weird that whatever I am doing is not working. I couldn't find any docs in nginx.

Comment: Where is your `http {` block compared to the above code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The original example cannot be used directly, because the main configuration is at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` has `http` directives, which includes the `sites-enabled/*` directives. The only changes to be made on `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` are:

```
work_processes 4;
worker_connections 1024;
```

Also, remove `text/html` from it because it's already gzipped by default.

The end result of your `nginx.conf` in your app should have no `http` directives, just `upstream` and `server`.